# How can get only date without time from a string contain date and time?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've a date like that `01/03/22 22:09` and I want to store it in `DB` just in a format of date like like that `'2022-03-01'`; I've tried *Regex* but still get time in *an hour:minute* too
How can I delete it?

```js
const date_time = '22/01/03 22:09';
const only_date = date_time.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})/,"'20$3-$2-$1'");
//console.log(only_date.substring(0,only_date.lastIndexOf("'")+1))
console.log(only_date)
```

PS: without using substring or slice... just with regex is there a way to do that?

Comment: [Replace `(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}).*` with `20$1-$3-$2`](https://regex101.com/r/ZttKf2/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `.*`

```js
const date_time = '22/01/03 22:09';
const only_date = date_time.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}).*/,"'20$3-$2-$1'");
console.log(only_date)
```